# JButton Wont Display JPanel

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I want to call My JPanel with button. My Jpanel is actually a sub JPanel from main Panel with card layout.

to  do that, i am using card layout api method [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show(java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String)) to show the JPanel after a button was clicked.

```
JButton btnCallPanel1 = new JButton("Call PanelOne");
   btnCallPanel1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            CardLayout card = (CardLayout)mainPanel.getLayout();
            card.show(mainPanel, "PanelOne");                     //call Panel One

        }
```

**output :**

nothing appear, panel not called and no error pop out.

My Code is [HERE](http://pastebin.com/DQcPxRRj)

```
package wan.dev.sample.cardlayout;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class HowToUseCardLayout {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HowToUseCardLayout window = new HowToUseCardLayout();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public HowToUseCardLayout() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 688, 358);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 672, 260);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

                JPanel PrePanel = new JPanel();
                mainPanel.add(PrePanel, "name_246268073832057");
                PrePanel.setLayout(null);

                        JLabel lblPanel_1 = new JLabel("Pre Panel");
                        lblPanel_1.setBounds(280, 115, 57, 20);
                        PrePanel.add(lblPanel_1);

        JPanel panelOne = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(panelOne, "name_246268067657434");
        panelOne.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblPanel = new JLabel("panel 1");
        lblPanel.setBounds(279, 118, 46, 14);
        panelOne.add(lblPanel);

        JButton btnPan1 = new JButton("Call PanelOne");
        btnPan1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                CardLayout card = (CardLayout) mainPanel.getLayout();
                card.show(mainPanel, "PanelOne");

            }
        });
        btnPan1.setBounds(262, 286, 144, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnPan1);
    }
}
```

**ANSWER**

The reason i cant call my panel because i did not call it by using identifier.
i have to give identifier name to my desire jpanel and use the identifier on my cardLayout.show(..)

```
Public Static final String PANEL_ONE = "panel one";                  //Name of JPanel Identifier


//add panel to main panel and declare panelOne identifier
mainPanel.add(panelOne, PANEL_ONE);                         //PANEL_ONE function like 
                                                            //an identifier


JButton btnCallPanel1 = new JButton("Call PanelOne");
btnCallPanel1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        CardLayout card = 
                     (CardLayout)mainPanel.getLayout();

        card.show(mainPanel, PANEL_ONE);                     //call panelOne using PANEL_ONE 
                                                             //instead of JPanel name

    }
```

Comment: could you explain what show function does?

Comment: You show a snippet of code, but I don't see that it's enough to diagnose your problem, so it appears that the question may be a  a `"guess what the code I'm not showing you is doing"` type question. Please fix this by creating and posting your [minimal code example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to review, test, and possibly fix.

Comment: @KickButtowski: the `show(...)` method is a CardLayout method. There's no problem with his use of this, unless his String literal parameter is off, and I can't tell if this is so based on the snippet presented. Myself, I like to use String constants when calling this method so that there is no chance of a mis-spell or capitalization problem.

Comment: Thanks for the attention, i have provided the code on the question post..feel free to view.

Comment: Does your code compile? The mainPanel local variable should not be usable within the ActionListener since it wasn't declared final. This code thus should not compile.

Comment: yes, i can compile, i try Next() method and it can change panel to another but not work with show()..i am sure the panel name provided to show() is correct..

Comment: @beNice: if you can compile it, then your final code is not the one you've posted. Period.

Comment: i test with System.out.println("hello") on ActionListener and it can print the statement. but other code within wont run

Comment: I've given the answer below.

Comment: Your "answer" above has a serious problem, in that the String constant you're using is the empty String, `""`. Please don't do this as this is brittle and risky code. You want your Strings to be more unique than that. `"panel one"` would be a much better String literal.

Comment: oh, thanks for the detection, my mistake..have edit it already..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I suspected — You're calling the `CardLayout.show(...)` method with the `String` parameter "PanelOne", but yet you've not added any component to the CardLayout-using container using this same String, so it makes sense that it won't work. Solution: don't do this. Use the Same String that you add the component to the CardLayout using container as the one that you use to display it.

i.e., If you want to display container foo and use the `String` `"bar"` to add it to the `CardLayout`-using container, then you must pass "bar" into the `CardLayout`'s `show(...)` method. Again, use String constants for this so that you reduce the chances of messing up.

Other issues: You're using `null` layout and `setBounds` — Don't. Doing this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CardLayoutFoo extends JPanel {
   public static final String BAR = "bar";
   public static final String BUTTON_PANEL = "button panel";
   private CardLayout cardlayout = new CardLayout();

   public CardLayoutFoo() {
      setLayout(cardlayout);

      JLabel fooLabel = new JLabel("Foo", SwingConstants.CENTER);
      add(fooLabel, BAR); // added using String constant, BAR

      JButton showFooBtn = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Show Foo") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            // use same String, BAR, to get the fooLabl shown
            cardlayout.show(CardLayoutFoo.this, BAR);
         }
      });
      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
      btnPanel.add(showFooBtn);
      add(btnPanel, BUTTON_PANEL);

      cardlayout.show(this, BUTTON_PANEL);            
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      CardLayoutFoo mainPanel = new CardLayoutFoo();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayoutFoo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels "Other issues: You're using null layout and setBounds — Don't."

what layout would be best for me to use? and how to avoid using setbound if we want to set the jframe or button to the size we desire

Comment: @beNice: that's right, "don't". You will want to read the layout manager tutorial (Google can help you or the [swing tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) can help), and then nest JPanels, each with its own layout and components.